# Angular Material test to click mat-button and open mat-menu

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-test

I'm trying to write a simple test that checks that a mat-menu is initially closed and then opens when a button is clicked. However, I'm having trouble getting the menu to open or finding any menu items to check for.

`help-button.component.html`:

```
<button
  mat-mini-fab
  id="helpBtn"
  aria-label="Help"
  title="Help"
  [matMenuTriggerFor]="helpMenu">
  <mat-icon id="helpIcon">question_mark</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-menu class="menu" #helpMenu="matMenu" id="helpMenu">
  <a
    mat-menu-item
    id="helpLink"
    href="example.com"
    target="_blank"
    >Help</a
  >
</mat-menu>
```

`help-button.component.spec.ts`:

```
import {
  ComponentFixture,
  TestBed,
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { HarnessLoader } from '@angular/cdk/testing';
import { TestbedHarnessEnvironment } from '@angular/cdk/testing/testbed';
import { MatMenuHarness } from '@angular/material/menu/testing';
import { MatButtonHarness } from '@angular/material/button/testing';
import { MatMenuItemHarness } from '@angular/material/menu/testing';

import { HelpButtonComponent } from './help-button.component';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';

describe('HelpButtonComponent', () => {
  let component: HelpButtonComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HelpButtonComponent>;
  let loader: HarnessLoader;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [MatMenuModule, MatFormFieldModule],
      declarations: [HelpButtonComponent],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HelpButtonComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should open help menu when clicking help button', async () => {
    const helpButton = await loader.getHarness<MatButtonHarness>(
      MatButtonHarness.with({
        selector: '[id="helpBtn"]',
      })
    );
    expect(helpButton).toBeTruthy();
    const helpMenu = await loader.getHarness<MatMenuHarness>(MatMenuHarness)

    expect(await helpMenu.isOpen()).toBeFalsy();
    await helpButton.click();
    expect(await helpMenu.isOpen()).toBeTruthy();

    //const helpLink = await loader.getHarness<MatMenuItemHarness>(MatMenuItemHarness)
    //console.log(helpLink)

    //const helpLink = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#helpLink'));
    //console.log('this one: ', helpLink)
    //expect(helpLink).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The test shows that `helpMenu` is falsy both before and after `helpButton.click()`. When I console logged `helpMenu.getItems()`, it was an empty array. I also tried getting the menu item (as you can see from the commented out code), but it was always a null value. I also tried only searching for the menu after `click()`, and tried using querySelector instead of harnesses, but it was the same outcome.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the NoopAnimationsModule in your imports:

https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/animations/NoopAnimationsModule

So import the Module:

`import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';`

and adjust your imports in `help-button.component.spec.ts` like this:

```
await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [MatMenuModule, MatFormFieldModule, NoopAnimationsModule],
    declarations: [HelpButtonComponent],
}).compileComponents();
```